# Flutter Firebase: How to check if return value is a specific object

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have implemented the below code. The problem is that I need to know whether the user account was created or not in order to forward the user to the homescreen. But since I am returning a Fluttertoast (to show the user an error message), I cannot return null. So I want to check whether the return value is a Fluttertoast. How can I do that? Or is there a better way to implement this?

```
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(
  {required String email,
  required String password,
  required String userName,
  required String gender}) async {
try {
  UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  User? user = result.user;
  // create a new document for the user with the uid
  await DatabaseService(uid: user!.uid)
      .updateUserData(gender: gender, userMail: email, userName: userName);
  return user;
} catch (error) {
  return Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: error.toString(),
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      textColor: Colors.white);
}
```

}

Basically I then want to implement an if statement to check whether the user account was created or not (then the fluttertoast is returned). Something like:

```
 if (result == FToast()) {
                              print("user not created");
                            }
```

Comment: Need more detailed code snippet to answer.

Comment: What part do you need exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning `null` instead of `Fluttertoast`.

Change you code as

```dart
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(
  {required String email,
  required String password,
  required String userName,
  required String gender}) async {
try {
  UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  User? user = result.user;
  // create a new document for the user with the uid
  await DatabaseService(uid: user!.uid)
      .updateUserData(gender: gender, userMail: email, userName: userName);
  return user;
} catch (error) {

  Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: error.toString(),
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      textColor: Colors.white);
return null;
}
```

Show the toast here and return the null.

So you can see the error in toast and late you can check whether the user created by the user value null or not.

```dart
if (result == null) {
     print("user not created");
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to check whether my user account is created. And (see above in my code) I am currently returning a fluttertoast, to show the user why his account was not created (e.g. email already used). But in a later step, I need to check whether the user was created, therefore I need to check if the return value is a user or a fluttertoast. Is my explanation clear?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. It's clear now. You dont need the error after the toast right?